# Selecting file but uploading entire parent folder

Tags: javascript, file-upload, fileapi

I need to upload the entire folder to the remote server and also pass the path of one specific file inside. I prefer doing this in a single step. Actually I use a desktop app: once specific file is selected, the parent folder is determined and all its content uploaded. IIRC web browsers don't allow accessing the content without user intention so I doubt listing siblings of the selected specific file will be ever possible. But maybe things are changing...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you are able to do this currently due to security measures already set in place to protect user privacy.